# When Git tells you it failed to push some refs,

Tags: git, heroku

I had installed rubyinstaller and msysgit, When I tried to deploy radiant to heroku, i was given the following warning message

```
$git push heroku master  //I use windows
  heroku receiving push
!heroku push rejected,repository is empty.
  to git@heroku.com:faculty.git
![remote rejected]master->master(pre-receive hook declined)
Error: failed to push some refs to git@heroku.com:faculty.git
```

and when I

```
$git push git@heroku.com:faculty.git
fatal:Couldn't fine remote ref HEAD
```

the HEAD really exists in a file which i read before.

when

```
 $git fetch git@heroku.com:faculty.git
    ssh: no address associated with name  // ssh key had been generated 
    fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

How to solve this problem? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Only a doubt, this is your first deploy this project? You have already setup SSH?

Try following these steps:

Download and install: https://toolbelt.herokuapp.com

Then do this command Heroku plugins: heroku plugins:install git://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts.git

arrow after your project: Heroku accounts: add faculty - auto

after try command push

Comment: How to do the commmand heroku plugins? Could you list them one by one in brief? Thanks in advance!

Comment: So just run this command: "heroku plugins:install git://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts.git", This is to manage multiple accounts on Heroku [More Details](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts/tree/e1ccdea3f13479aff11df3176c0245bb60855f67)