# Heroku: 'Push rejected, repository is empty' on Cloud9 IDE

Tags: heroku, cloud9-ide

I'm working on Cloud9 IDE, and I just attempted to deploy to Heroku, but I got this error:

```
[1/5] Verifying preconditions...
[2/5] Updating repository...
[3/5] Pushing to Heroku...
1:: Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '50.19.85.154' to the list of known hosts.
!     Push rejected, repository is empty
To git@heroku.com:anthro-site.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:anthro-site.git'
```

I looked around and found a few questions here that are similar, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687235/when-git-tells-you-it-failed-to-push-some-refs), but unfortunately the answer to that question requires me to install software, and I don't think I'm allowed to do that on Cloud9. I don't seem to have access to the `heroku` command, so it must not have been installed for me. How do I proceed?

Comment: Are you sure you have pushed your code to Cloud9 before? It seems the repo on Cloud9 is empty, and it can't push to heroku because there is nothing to push. Either that or the commit is empty.

Comment: @ChristianStewart what do you mean "pushed [my] code to Cloud9"? I wrote my code _on_ Cloud9. Why would I have to push it anywhere except Heroku?

Comment: @ChristianStewart I do wonder if I need my code to be on my `origin/master`, but I'd rather not for organizational reasons. Do you think that could be my problem?

Comment: My apologies, not really sure how Cloud9 works. Have you made any commits? And yes, the code should be in the master branch (that's the branch Heroku looks for).

Comment: @ChristianStewart Oh. It's an online IDE, so you write/run code there, and optionally push to other places like GitHub, BitBucket or Heroku. I've made quite a few commits and successfully pushed them to GitHub. I can't imagine why Heroku thinks my repository is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you can install the Heroku client on Cloud9, as described [here](https://docs.c9.io/deploying_via_cli.html):

> > To deploy to Heroku, type the following commands:
> >
> > ```
> > wget http://assets.heroku.com/heroku-client/heroku-client.tgz
> > tar xzfv heroku-client.tgz
> > cd heroku-client/bin
> > PATH=$PATH:$PWD
> > ```
> >
> > Now, you can use the heroku command for your projects, as described in the Heroku documentation.

But that wasn't my problem. It seems in order to push to heroku, you must be on your `master` branch. The steps for me were as follows:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge dev # that's the branch I was working on
                # if you don't merge, master will not have whatever
                # commits you've made to the branch you were on.
$ git push --set-upstream heroku master
```

after that I waited for Heroku to finish installing my app, and now I can access it.

Answer (score 0):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploying-code

> Branches pushed to Heroku other than master will be ignored by this
>   command. If you’re working out of another branch locally, you can
>   either merge to master before pushing, or specify that you want to
>   push your local branch to a remote master. To push a branch other than
>   master, use this syntax:
>
> `$ git push heroku yourbranch:master`

It worked for me.